# Criar post em um wordpress e trazer em outro wordpress automaticamente

Tags: php, wordpress, loop, post, woocommerce

Opções:

- Criar um novo POST em um wordpress-1, a partir de outro wordpress-2.

ou

- Tudo que for criado no wordpress-2 ser "copiado" para o wordpress-1

ou

- Criar/Cadastrar um produto em uma loja(site)-1, a partir de outra loja(site)-2. [[RESOLVIDO]](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-vendors/screenshots/)

Eu já usei o multsite integrado com o ThreeWP-Broadcast, mas apresenta bugs estranhos, tais como deslogar-se automaticamente do admin quando alterno o dashboard.

> [UPDATE]
>   Utilizar o mesmo banco, alterando lá no wp-config, não dar certo! Pois
>   o wordpress trabalha com links permanentes e vai trazer uma URL fixa e
>   no caso, não devo acessar o site 1 através do site 2, mas somente
>   devem ter os mesmos post!

Comment: conseguiu resolver esse problema? fiquei curioso

Comment: Não, @CaioFelipePereira, mas vou analisar sua resposta. Vi agora.

Comment: Você está falando de Multisite ou de dois WP independentes?

Comment: WP independentes.

Answer (score 5):

Fazer isso automaticamente me parece meio complicado, mas acho que é possível. A solução que eu vou sugerir não foi testada mas, em teoria, acho que deve funcionar. Vou chamar de `w1` o WordPress no qual você quer criar o post, e de `w2`o WordPress que irá receber os posts, assim que eles forem criados no primeiro.

1. Mantenha a integridade entre os dois sites

   Esse eu acredito que deveria ser o passo zero, mas enfim. Se você tem algum tipo de customização nos posts de `w1`, como `meta data`, `custom fields` e coisas do tipo, e não tem *pelo menos* a mesma estrutura no `w2`, o post que você está querendo duplicar não será duplicado 100% corretamente. Portanto, garanta que `w2` tenha, no mínimo, todas as propriedades definidas por você em `w1`.
2. Crie um *action hook* para a publicação de posts em `w1`

   O WP tem uma série de *actions* pré-definidas, e atrelar alguma funcionalidade a mais a elas é tido como a criação de um hook. A *action* que vamos usar é a [publish_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post). Do codex:

   > publish_post is an action triggered whenever a post is published, or if it is edited and the status is changed to publish.

   Ou seja, toda vez que você publicar um post, alguma coisa (que você definir) vai acontecer. Em termos de código, esse é o esqueleto que você coloca no `functions.php`:

   ```
   add_action('publish_post', 'replicar_post_em_w2');
   function replicar_post_em_w2(){
       # code...
   }
   ```

   Basicamente, `replicar_posts_em_w2()` vai ser chamada no momento da publicação. Volto pra este método em breve.
3. Criar uma interface de inserção de posts em `w2`

   Existe mais de um jeito de você fazer isso, mas um que eu particularmente gosto, é usando o plugin [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/#2.2.-Pages-controller-methods) (A partir desse ponto, toda minha resposta baseia-se neste plugin). Ele proporciona métodos de consulta - que devolvem um `JSON` baseando-se em uma `URL` e em seus parâmetros - e também métodos de criação de posts (o que nos interessa), que funciona basicamente da mesma maneira. Você chama uma `URL` do tipo `http://w2.com/api/create_post/?nonce=123abc&content=blablabla`, e ele cria o post pra você. Falando especificamente deste plugin, existe um método chamado `get_nonce()` que deve ser usado pra gerar o `nonce`, que é um parâmetro necessário para o método `create_post()`. Leia sobre os pormenores do plugin [aqui](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/).
4. Chame, dentro do *action hook*, o seu método de inserção em `w2`

   Agora que você já tem (ou deve ter) pronta, e testada, a estrutura de inserção de posts em `w2`, está na hora de construir o método de replicação propriamente dito. Como você vai trabalhar com um `post`, você deve fornecê-lo como parâmetro para este método. Dentro dele, você vai extrair o que você precisa do post que acabou de criar em `w1`, montar uma *query string* usando [este](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) método, e chamar a `URL` de inserção de `w2` para que o processo se complete. De uma maneira bem simples, seu código seria:

   ```
   function replicar_post_em_w2($post){
       $url_de_insercao = 'http://w2.com/api/create_post/?';

       $titulo = $post->title;
       $couteudo = $post->content;
       $nonce = '123abc'; 
       #... E por aí vai

       $query_params = array(
           'nonce' => $nonce,
           'title' => $title,
           'content' => $conteudo
       );

       $url_de_insercao .= http_build_query($query_params);

       $ch = curl_init();

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_de_insercao);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

       curl_exec($ch);

       curl_close($ch);

   }
   ```

   Note que usei `cURL` pra chamar o método de inserção em `w2`. Note também que o valor do `nonce` foi arbitrário. Você pode usar o `cURL` para fazer a requisição em `w2` para pegar o valor correto. A lista de parâmetros de todos os métodos do plugin encontra-se na [documentação](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/).

   Por fim, como agora o seu método recebe um parâmetro, você tem que alterar o `add_action` para:

   ```
   add_action('publish_post', 'replicar_post_em_w2', 10, 1);
   ```

   Onde 10 é a prioridade, e 1 é o número de argumentos de `replicar_post_em_w2`.

Acredito que, se você seguir esses passos, vai alcançar o seu objetivo. Claro que você vai ter um bom trabalho de debug pela frente, e a inserção dos posts pode ser meio chata, principalmente por conta do `nonce`. A construção da `query` pode ser meio complexa também, e se você estiver trabalhando com `custom posts`, talvez a inserção se complique um pouco. De qualquer maneira, a teoria é essa. Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Poderia atualizar? (Tinha que ser um Brasileiro para simplificar algo tão problemático....)

Comment: @PauloBoaventura felizmente minha carreira me levou para longe do wordpress e eu imagino (na verdade, espero) que as coisas tenham mudado bastante dentro dele e que essa resposta tenha deixado de ser coerente. Ademais, meu conhecimento no WP já é obsoleto. Sugiro que faça uma pesquisa nas APIs que são disponibilizadas e veja o que (ainda) faz sentido

Answer (score 4):

[Conforme o (grande) Frank Bueltge](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213674/two-live-wp-websites-how-to-sync/213686#213686), existem tres métodos para fazer isso:

1. [WP API (JSON)](http://v2.wp-api.org/)
2. [Feed (XML)](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds)
3. [XMLRPC API](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API)

E, ainda segundo Bueltge, deveriamos priorizar o WP JSON API pois é a maneira mais moderna e está a ponto de ser incorporada no código base do WordPress. Porém, minha resposta é via XMLRPC, um método clássico do WP (para fazer trackbacks e pingbacks, publicar desde web ou desktop apps), e que normalmente [recomenda-se](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2013/08/disable-xml-rpc-wordpress.html) desabilitar porque abre a porta a diversas tentativas de ataque <sup>**[vide "segurança" ao final]**</sup>.

**Observações**:

- este código é só uma prova de conceito; o post de origem é reproduzido no site destino, mas essa informação não é armazenada no site de origem;
- um código completo teria que armazenar o ID do post "espelho" no site de origem. E, ao ser chamada outra vez, em vez de criar um novo post de novo, teria que atualizar o post "espelho" que foi criado primeiro e cujo ID armazenamos como `add_post_meta` ao fazer a reprodução;
- o site destino devolve o ID do post espelho que foi criado, então a funcionalidade acima não é muito difícil, são necessários um pouco de jQuery e AJAX.

### Plugin Destino

<sup>Instalado no site que vai **receber** o post duplicado.</sup>

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOpt) Plugin de Destino
 * Description: Publicações DE outro site
 * Plugin URI: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66280
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: brasofilo 
 */

add_filter( 'xmlrpc_methods', 'xmlrpc_sopt_66280' );

function xmlrpc_sopt_66280( $methods ) {
    /* BLOQUEIO DE TODOS OS MÉTODOS, remova a seguinte linha para habilitar todos os métodos padão do WP */
    $methods = array();
    $methods['postFromOutside'] = 'outside_sopt_66280';
    return $methods;
}

function outside_sopt_66280( $args ) {
    // A ordem dos argumentos é importante!
    $username   = $args[0];
    $password   = $args[1];
    $data = $args[2];  
    global $wp_xmlrpc_server;

    // Usuário correto?
    if ( !$user = $wp_xmlrpc_server->login( $username, $password ) ) {
        return $wp_xmlrpc_server->error;
    }

    // Titulo e custom fields do post
    $title = $data["title"];
    $custom_fields = $data["custom_fields"];

    // Formatar o novo post
    $new_post = array(
        'post_status' => 'draft',
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_type' => 'post',
    );

    // Faz o insert do novo post
    $new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );
    foreach( $custom_fields as $meta_key => $values )
        foreach ( $values as $meta_value )
            add_post_meta( $new_post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    // Devolve ID do novo post
    return $new_post_id;
}
```

### Plugin de Origem

<sup>Instalado no site que vai **criar** post duplicado.</sup>

**`/wp-content/plugins/xml-post/xml-post.php`**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOpt) Plugin de Origem
 * Description: Publicações PARA outro site. CONFIGURAR 'user' e 'password' do Site Destino.
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54875/12615
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: brasofilo 
 */

add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse_54822_add_custom_box' );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse_54822_script_enqueuer' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse_54822_custom_query', 'wpse_54822_custom_query' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse_54822_custom_query', 'wpse_54822_custom_query' );

function wpse_54822_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'wpse_54822_sectionid',
        __( 'Page Attachments' ), 
        'wpse_54822_inner_custom_box',
        'page'
    );
}

function wpse_54822_inner_custom_box() {
    global $post;
    ?>
        <a href="#" id="post-me" class="dettach" title="Cross post" >Post Me</a>
    <?php
}

function wpse_54822_script_enqueuer() {
    global $current_screen;
    if( 'page' != $current_screen->id )
        return;
    wp_register_script( 'my-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/ajax-xmlrpc.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js' );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-js', 'wp_ajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); 
}

function wpse_54822_custom_query() {
    // Dados a enviar na chamada XML-RPC
    $data = array(
        "title" => 'titulo',
        "custom_fields" => 'custom_fields'
    );    
    // Considerando que user e password são "admin" e "admin"
    // E que o método postFromOutside é o que está definido no Plugin Destino
    $params = array( 'admin', 'admin', $data );
    $params = xmlrpc_encode_request( 'postFromOutside', $params );   
    // Iniciar a requisição HTTP
    $request = new WP_Http;
    $result = $request->request(
        'http://plugins.dev/xmlrpc.php',
        array('method' => 'POST', 'body' => $params )
    );
    // O retorno XML é EXTREMAMENTE ESPECÍFICO e depende do Plugin de Origem
    $xml = simplexml_load_string( $result['body'] );
    wp_send_json_success( $xml->params->param->value->int );
}
```

**`/wp-content/plugins/xml-post/ajax-xmlrpc.js`**

```
/**
 * Arquivo JS que acompanha o plugin XML-POST.PHP
 * O objeto wp_ajax é enviado pelo wp_localize_script
 * A propriedade the_id é somente ilustrativa 
 */
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    $('#post-me').click(function(){
        $.post( 
            wp_ajax.ajaxurl, 
            { 
                action: 'wpse_54822_custom_query', 
                the_id: 'toast' 
            }, 
            function(data){
                console.log('Novo Post:',data.data[0]);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

### [Segurança]

- Crie um usuário no Site Destino somente para a conexão XMLRPC; pode usar  nome  e senha tipo 128bits; ou seja, bem complicados.
- Talvez queira armazenar `user` e `password` em um arquivo de configuração fora da pasta `public_html` e fazer um `require/include` para puxar isso .
- Pelo que vi, tem alguns métodos [específicos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9609415/1287812) que são alvos preferidos de ataques DDoS e a prevenção é fazer o `unset()` desse métodos. Com a linha `$methods = array();` no Plugin de Destino estamos apagando **todos** os métodos padrão e adicionando só o nosso logo em seguida.
- Sugiro duas ferramentas de segurança: o plugin [WordFence](https://www.wordfence.com/) e as regras de `.htaccess` [5G Blacklist 2013](https://perishablepress.com/5g-blacklist-2013/).

Referências:

- [Custom XML-RPC Methods in WordPress – Konstantin Kovshenin](https://kovshenin.com/2010/custom-xml-rpc-methods-in-wordpress/)
- [How to get WordPress posts from a single category using XML-RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25507463/1287812)
- [How to validate a user from ouside wordpress/php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/39662/12615)

Comment: Perfeito. Resolvido.

Comment: @brasofilo Poderia atualizar? Neste caso é " importado" as imagens?

Comment: @PauloBoaventura, não, esse código não lida com exportar/importar as imagens anexas ao post. Hoje em dia é melhor trabalhar com a WP Rest API, já está tudo bem documentado e existem bons exemplos no [so] e no [wordpress.se]

Comment: @brasofilo me referia ao trazer o outro post automaticamente... As imagem anexas a estes posts vão para o outro post? São excluídas? ou fazem alguma referencia...  Teria a possibilidade de incorporar um código para que isso possa ser feito juntamente?

Comment: @PauloBoaventura Que eu saiba, isso só acontece ao fazer o export/import nativo do WordPress (é um arquivo XML). Certamente haverá plugins/serviços que oferecem isso. Quando você exporta um post, ele tem no HTML do conteúdo `<img src="https://siteoriginal.com/.../imagem.jpg">` mas o XML do WP também exporta os "attachments". O export/import default do WP vai cuidar de fazer download da imagem e trocar a URL e cuidar de tudo mais. Qualquer outro export/import tem que ser explicito "Vou cuidar das imagens/anexos!", senão não vai fazer.

Comment: Aqui é uma gambiarra que arrumei pra importar arquivos/imagens da sua máquina para o servidor usando o XML do WP: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/87407/12615

Answer (score 0):

Você pode editar o arquivo `wp-config.php` nas duas instalações Wordpress para que eles apontem para o mesmo banco de dados.

Dessa forma, tudo que for criado através de um irá aparecer automaticamente no outro.

Comment: Mas como vão apontar pro mesmo banco, se possuem URL diferentes? Digo...Quando for em uma interna, por exemplo, irei para a url que está no banco. `Site 1: www.site.com.br/wordpress` - `Site 2 :www.site.com.br/wordpress/mobile` - PODE ATUALIZAR A RESPOSTA?

Comment: @Lollipop ao invés do endereço do banco apontar para localhost ele pode apontar para a outra URL.

Comment: Mano, entenda...São dois wordpress. Quando eu obter o post do banco, NO SITE 2, ele vai me trazer `www.site.com.br/contato` que pertence ao site1 e vai me redirecionar para ele. Mas o problema é que o site 1 nunca deve ser aberto pelo site 2. Mas tudo que houver no site 1 deve haver no site 2. Ta claro?

Comment: Veja o update da minha pergunta.

Comment: Sem maiores detalhes, esta resposta é uma receita perfeita para um problema bem grande.