# Imagens do RSS não aparecem no Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, back-end

Estou tentando puxar um *RSS* de um outro site *wordpress*, para o meu que também é *wordpress*. O conteúdo escrito aparece normal, mas o *thumbnail* da foto não aparece.

Alguém poderia me informar se é possível listar 2 posts de outro site *wordpress*, sendo que o mesmo não está no mesmo servidor de hospedagem que o meu?

> Obs: 
>    Tenho acesso aos arquivos deste outro site.

Comment: cara, dando um chute BEM longo, veja se essa resposta, que dei faz um tempo, lhe ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66280/criar-post-em-um-wordpress-e-trazer-em-outro-wordpress-automaticamente/66535#66535

Comment: como voce esta fazendo o leitor do rss? eu fiz um porém puxei a primeira imagem que vem no post, nao consegui utilizar a thumbnail do wordperss